# Opening files from vim-fugitive's :GcLog

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-fugitive

When I'm in `:GcLog` how do I go to the source file? The documentation shows:

> `<CR>`                    Open the file or |fugitive-object| under the cursor.

But, I've only been able to open up "fugitive-objects" with `<CR>` and not the actual file. How can I do this?

Comment: The doc I have says: `Use git-log [args] to load the commit history into the |quickfix| list.`  It is suppose to list all the commits of the repository. I'm not sure Could you give us an example of your `GcLog` output with and indication of the `file` entries?

Comment: See selected answer. I believe there are only fugitive objects in this mode.

Comment: That was also my understanding :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are only fugitive objects in this view, I'm not sure you can go directly to the file from here. I know you can do it in 2 steps, however. Given this diff:

```
diff --git a/.github/workflows/tox-fedora.yml b/.github/workflows/tox-fedora.yml
index 381a0b0c51d0..4e88cee48afd 100644
--- a/.github/workflows/tox-fedora.yml
+++ b/.github/workflows/tox-fedora.yml
@@ -8,7 +8,7 @@ jobs:
```

If you place your cursor on one of the lines starting with `---` or `+++` then press `<CR>`, then do `:Gedit` (or `1<CR>` if the line you're on is still in the working tree version), this will open the working tree version of the file that you can then edit.

See `:h fugitive-navigation-maps`:

```
                                                fugitive_<CR>
<CR>                    Open the file or fugitive-object under the cursor.
                        In a blob, this and similar maps jump to the patch
                        from the diff where this was added, or where it was
                        removed if a count was given.  If the line is still in
                        the work tree version, passing a count takes you to
                        it.
```

Comment: This seems like the right answer. I believe you're correct that there are only fugitive objects in that view.